# How can I increase the transmission power of Wi-Fi in Redmi 1S running Kitkat?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, miui

I am using a Redmi 1S mobile running MIUI 6 on KitKat. The mobile is rooted.

Is there any way to increase the Wi-Fi transmission power of my mobile?

**Things I've tried:**

1. I have tried using `iwconfig` in terminal emulator.
2. I have tried WiFi tx power app from play store.
   Both of these didn't work for me.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually the tx power is already at the maximum value. Even `iwconfig` won't be able to increase it, it would have already increased it, if it wasn't at the maximum value.

Comment: @GiantTree I tried decreasing the power but that too didn't work.